Awaiting ClientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync only receives one packet of information, and then all other awaits never return
I'm using the System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket class in C# on .NET 6.0.
I have a timer set up that repeatedly will poll the websocket for connections, shown here. The timer is elapsed every 16 ms.
When the packet is received, it'll deserialize it as JSON and create an event. This works, but it only does it once.
I added the print lines for testing:
Console.WriteLine("Awaiting started") 

and
Console.WriteLine("Awaiting ended")

Awaiting started should be printed when the websocket is polled. It should print "Awaiting ended" after the websocket has finished the polling, and then if the packet received isn't empty, it'll deserialize it.
private async void poll(Object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs event_args) 
{
    switch (web_socket.State) 
    {
        case WebSocketState.Open: 
            {
                if (socket_connected == false) 
                {
                    socket_connected = true;
                }

                try 
                {
                    // ReceiveAsync automatically polls and receives the packet.
                    Memory<Byte> memory = new Memory<Byte>(new Byte[1024]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Awaiting started");
                    ValueWebSocketReceiveResult result = await web_socket.ReceiveAsync(memory, CancellationToken.None);
                    Console.WriteLine("Awaiting ended");

                    // Only attempt deserialization if a packet was received, aka the buffer is not empty.
                    if (result.Count != 0) 
                    {
                        deserialize_event(memory.Slice(0, result.Count).ToArray());
                    }
                } 
                catch (Exception exception) 
                { 
                    Console.WriteLine("Pusher polling error: " + exception.ToString());
                }
            } 
            break;

        case WebSocketState.Closed: 
            {
                connection_closed(web_socket.CloseStatus);
            } 
            break;
    }
}

What's supposed to happen: it should first print that its awaiting, then await the packet, then write the contents to the buffer, then move on with the execution, printing that the Await ended.
What actually happens:

It looks like it only receives one singular packet, and then all calls to ReceiveAsync never finish.

Typo alert: it's correctly spelled receive (not "recieve" ...)

Using a timer will call ReceiveAsync again before the previous call is complete, which is not supported.

Exactly one send and one receive is supported on each ClientWebSocket
object in parallel. Issuing multiple sends or multiple receives at the
same time (for example, without awaiting, or from multiple threads
without synchronization) is not supported and will result in an
undefined behavior.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket?view=net-8.0
Instead of invoking the read from a timer, create a thread (or Long Lived Task), and invoke await websocket.ReceiveAsync in a loop.

Thank you for this. I modified it to use a thread, and now it will no longer will start requesting another receive operation if the previous one has not yet completed.
However, the problem of only receiving one event still persists. It receives the first event, and then instead of spamming the console with "Awaiting started", it only prints it once as the await operation never finishes.
After a few minutes of real time, an exception is raised over the line with the RecieveAsync function:
SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

Is the other end sending more messages?

It should be. I wrote this program once already before in another language, and it is supposed to be receiving more messages.
